# Click a link to delete targeted content using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, ajax, django

I used a glyphicon as a link to delete a comment:

```
<a class="delCommentLink" href="{% url 'article:comment_delete' comment.id %}">
    <span id="{{ comment.id }}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true">delete</span>
</a>
```

I send the request using Ajax.

1. retrieve the `comment_url`
2. get the grand-grand-parent element to hide
3. send request to `views.py` and delete the target comment

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on("click",".delCommentLink",function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var comment_url = $(e.target).parent().attr("href");
        var $commentEle = $(e.target).closest(".comment");
        if (window.confirm("Delete this comment?")) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: comment_url,
                success: function (data) {
                    var ret = JSON.parse(data);
                    if (ret['status'] == 1) {
                        $commentEle.hide();
                    } else {
                        alert(ret['msg']);
                };
            },//success
        });//ajax  
        } else {
            e.preventDefault()
        }
    });//click event
})
```

Click a link to delete it. My code seems like it has too many lines for such a routine task.

How can I complete it elegantly?

Answer (score 2):

I only see two things to "reduce", regarding the line amount.

1. The `if` statement in the success callback could be replaced by a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
2. The last `e.preventDefault()` is redundant, you can squarely remove the whole else part.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $("body").on("click",".delCommentLink",function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var comment_url = $(e.target).parent().attr("href");
       var $commentEle = $(e.target).closest(".comment");
       if (window.confirm("Delete this comment?")) {
         $.ajax({
           type: "get",
           url: comment_url,
           success: function (data) {
             var ret = JSON.parse(data);
             (ret['status'] == 1) ? $commentEle.hide() : alert(ret['msg']);
           },//success
         });//ajax  
       }
     });//click event
   });
   ```

That is 6 lines less...

Answer (score 1):

Louys has already mentioned a couple great techniques. There are a few others:

- Use the shortcut method [`$.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) passing the URL as the first parameter and the success callback as the second parameter
- Do elements with the class "*delCommentLink*" get added to the page after the page is loaded or do they all exist when the page is loaded? If the latter is the case then the alias [`$.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) could be used instead of the `$.on()` method.

Additionally:

- You didn't mention which version of jQuery is used/supported, but presuming it is 3.0 or higher (correct me if that is incorrect) the form `$(document).ready(handler)` is deprecated<sup>[1](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)</sup> and the only supported form is `$(handler)` so the code could be updated like below.
- Instead of using bracket notation for accessing a property of the return value:

  > ```
  >  ret['status']
  > ```

  It can be done using dot notation:

  ```
  ret.status
  ```

Simpler code:

```
$(function () { // DOM ready callback
    $("body").on("click", ".delCommentLink", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var comment_url = $(e.target).parent().attr("href");
        var $commentEle = $(e.target).closest(".comment");
        if (window.confirm("Delete this comment?")) {
            $.get(comment_url, function (data) {
                var ret = JSON.parse(data);
                ret.status == 1 ? $commentEle.hide() : alert(ret['msg']);
            });//ajax  
        }
    });//click event
}); // DOM ready callback
```